# Routing and authenticating all access through squid

Tags: proxy, squid, gateway, internet

I want to route all Internet access in my network through a Squid proxy server and authenticate and log all users. I want this to be a client-independent setting so that no one needs to do anything on their browsers or machines.

I have set my network gateway as the proxy server so that all traffic will be sent to it. I have done this using options in DHCP server.

1. Now I tried using **squid as a transparent proxy,** but then it won't authenticate in that mode.
2. I tried using **iptables to route all traffic** to port 3128 but **it won't popup the authentication** dialog box from SQUID.
3. I tried telling **DHCP to give WPAD** to all clients by placing a **WPAD file** on a webserver containing the following for automatic proxy configuration on clients:

   Changes in **dhcpd.conf**

> option wpad code 252 =test;
>
> option wpad "\n\000";
>
> option wpad "http://192.168.1.5/wpad.dat\n";

**The WPAD file:**

> function FindProxyForURL(url,host)
>
> {
>
> return "PROXY squid-server-ip-address:3128 ; DIRECT ";
>
> }

But the browsers (different versions of Firefox and IE) seem to ignore it. :(

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think your DHCP options may be off... 
From: http://www.wlug.org.nz/WPAD

> Add the following to your
>   /etc/dhcpd.conf:
>
> option option-252
>   "http://wpad.host.co.nz/proxy.pac";
>
> With ISC DHCP v3+, option-# options
>   don't work. You have to do this in the
>   global section of your configuration:
>
> option wpad-url    code 252 = text;
>   (define a new option)
>
> And add this in either the global or
>   appropriate subnet section(s) of your
>   configuration:
>
> option wpad-url
>   "http://wpad.my.domain.tld/proxy.pac\n";
>   (use new option)

Also, you will find that auth in transparent mode in squid is not really possible. Some commercial web filters do work around this (indeed I work for [SmoothWall](http://www.smoothwall.net), one such filter).

Comment: LOVE the SmoothWall, Tom.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton Tom! :D

This takes care of all the Internet Explorers out there in the network. But Firefox and Konqueror don't autodetect these settings. I will try the DNS method from the URL you mentioned. 

Thanks again! :)

Comment: You might try adding a dns record for wpad.yourdomain - though if your client (windows) PCs all have different domain settings it might get hairy. Check your logs, see who is looking up what, wpad wise.

Also worth downloading wireshark and and looking at what exactly each browser is doing when it fails.